# Variable not displayed in console.log

Tags: javascript

here is my code.

```
let userName = 'dave'
userName = userName ? console.log(`Hello, ${userName}`) : console.log('Hello!')

let userQuestion = 'Am I crazy'
console.log(`${userName} asked: ${userQuestion}`)
```

expected output

```
Hello, dave
dave asked: Am I crazy
```

actual output

```
Hello, dave
undefined asked: Am I crazy
```

Why is it showing 'undefined` ?

Comment: You assigned it to the result of `console.log(...)`, which is `undefined`.

Comment: The second line should be `console.log(userName ? \`Hello, ${userName}\` : 'Hello!'`)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are trying to assign the console.log to userName and using it. change the code to

```js
let userName = 'dave'
console.log(userName ? `Hello, ${userName}` : 'Hello!');

let userQuestion = 'Am I crazy'
console.log(`${userName} asked: ${userQuestion}`)
```

or you can use the line as follows.

```
userName ? console.log(`Hello, ${userName}`) : console.log('Hello!')
```

```js
let userName = 'dave'
userName ? console.log(`Hello, ${userName}`) : console.log('Hello!');


let userQuestion = 'Am I crazy'
console.log(`${userName} asked: ${userQuestion}`)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I see it now.

As newbie to JS it's both amazing and daunting that these two statements are the same.  Which one would be considered better code style, or more customary?

1) userName ? console.log(`Hello, ${userName}`) : console.log('Hello!')

2) console.log(userName ? `Hello, ${userName}` : 'Hello!');

Comment: I recommend `console.log(userName ? `Hello, ${userName}` : 'Hello!');`

Answer (score 2):

```
userName = userName ? console.log(`Hello, ${userName}`) : console.log('Hello!')
```

This line of code changes the content of the variable **userName** by whatever the **console.log()** return. And they return undefined

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning incorrect value in the second line, which makes it undefined.

```js
let userName = 'dave'
//userName = userName ? console.log(`Hello, ${userName}`) : console.log('Hello!')
console.log(userName ? `Hello, ${userName}` : 'Hello!')

let userQuestion = 'Am I crazy'
console.log(`${userName} asked: ${userQuestion}`)
```